# Add errors into errors block without throw

Tags: ecmascript-6, graphql, graphql-js

I am trying to find a way to insert some errors inside GraphQL `errors` block from a type's `resolve` function, I found that I need to do something like this when I have multiple `put` requests inside the same `mutation function`.

```
function promises() {
  const proms = requests.map(service => {
    service().then(() => ({ success: true }))
    .catch(() => ({ success: false, errorCode: 'some error' }))
  })
  Promise.all(proms)
}

someType: {
 name: 'SomeType',
 resolve: async val => {
   const resp = await promises();
   // extract the errors in push them to GraphQL errors 
   // display the rest of the data
 }
}
```